# How add picture in gridview when take more pictures

Tags: android, gridview

When Camera icon is clicked it will take a photo. Then want save pictures in `gridview` below

[image: when click picture camera when will take a photo. Then will save pictures in gridview below]

Comment: what you have tried before?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to implement it in [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) instead of GridView, and everytime you take a picture using camera, update the RecyclerViewAdapter by notifyDatasetChanged() method. You will get lots of examples in github for RecyclerView as well as Camera feature.

Before asking any such question please try to implement  and write code.